# How to decrease the days remaining when the days are passed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Thank you in advance,
I am new to Django rest
I am creating a JobsPortal website with Django rest but the problem is when the days pass the days remaining is still the same. How to decrease the days remaining when the days are passed. And also how to delete the data automatically after the before date is passed.

My model

```
class Jobs(models.Model):
    post_date=models.DateField( default=_datetime.date.today, blank=False,editable=False)
    before_date=models.DateField(blank=False,)
    days_left=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    
     def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.days_left=((self.before_date - self.post_date).days)
        if self.days_left>=0:
          super(Jobs, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return  False
```

Comment: From what I understood, you are storing the remaining days on you database and update the days_left each time you save a Jobs instance, but this will update the days_left only if you keep saving all the instances everyday. You only need to keep in you database the post_date and calculate the days left in your class method. You could add a boolean field to activate or deactivate the Jobs class, no need to delete the data as someone would want to relist the job or you want to keep the information for making a report.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store this in the model as a field, since this is functionally completely determined by `before_date`. We thus can make it a property like:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Job(models.Model):
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    before_date = models.DateField()
    
    @property
    def days_left(self):
        return (self.before_date - now().date()).days
```

If you for example want to retrieve all the jobs that have less than 10 days left, we can work with:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
from datetime import timedelta

Job.objects.filter(before_date__gte=now()-timedelta(days=10))
```